# How to parameterize aliased paths in babel's `Module Resolver`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Using ***babel-plugin-module-resolver*** I would like to alias paths using more than one paramters.

I have the following paths:

> /foo/components/filename.jsx
>
> /bar/components/filename.jsx

I would like to alias these paths with a single regex in such a way that:

> import * from '@foo/filename' ---> import * from '/foo/components/filename'

Namely, **@{foldername}/{filename}** becomes **/{foldername}/components/{filename}**

Thank you

Comment: Can’t you do this in your typescript config paths?

Comment: The project I'm working on is not using typescript

Answer (score 0):

You can make configuration in .babelrc file

> `{
>     "plugins": [
>       [
>         "module-resolver",
>         {
>           "cwd": "babelrc",
>           "root": ["./"],
>           "alias": {
>             "@foo": "./foo/components",
>             "@bar": "./bar/components",
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     ]
>   }`

Just make sure you fill '"root":' where ./foo and ./bar placed

Comment: This doesn't resolve the issue. I don't want to have to add an alias for every folder in my project